# Reading and initializing json data with scalatest withFixture

Tags: json, scala, scalatest

I am trying to use `withFixture` method to initialize my `var ip2GeoTestJson` and use it throughout my tests. I was able to achieve the desired logic with `var year`. I believe the error I am getting (parsing `JNothing`) is caused because the `withFixture` is not initializing my `ip2GeoTestJson` with the JSON.

I am currently getting this error:

```
*** RUN ABORTED ***
  An exception or error caused a run to abort: java.lang.ClassCastException was thrown scenario("event.client_ip_address and event_header.client_ip_address both have values") -, construction cannot continue: "org.json4s.JsonAST$JNothing$ cannot be cast to org.json4s.JsonAST$JObject" (IP2GeoTestSuite.scala:51)
```

Code:

```
class IP2GeoTestSuite extends FeatureSpec with SparkContextFixture {
  var ip2GeoTestJson: JValue = null
  var year: String = null      

  feature("feature") {
    scenario("scenario") {
      println(ip2GeoTestJson)
      assert(year != null)
      assert(ip2GeoTestJson != null)
    }
  }

  def withFixture(test: NoArgTest): org.scalatest.Outcome = {
    year = test.configMap("year").asInstanceOf[String]
    val ip2GeoConfigFile = test.configMap("config").asInstanceOf[String]
    val ip2GeoUrl = getClass.getResourceAsStream(s"/$ip2GeoConfigFile")
    val ip2GeoJsonString = Source.fromInputStream(ip2GeoUrl).getLines.mkString("")
    System.out.println(ip2GeoJsonString)
    ip2GeoTestJson = parse(ip2GeoJsonString)
    try {
      test()
    }
  }
}
```

The code works fine when the lines regarding `ip2GeoData` are moved to the top of the class like so however I need to hardcode the file name:

```
class IP2GeoTestSuite extends FeatureSpec with SparkContextFixture {
    val ip2GeoConfigFile = "ip2geofile.json"
    val ip2GeoUrl = getClass.getResourceAsStream(s"/$ip2GeoConfigFile")
    val ip2GeoJsonString = Source.fromInputStream(ip2GeoUrl).getLines.mkString("")
    System.out.println(ip2GeoJsonString)
    val ip2GeoTestJson = parse(ip2GeoJsonString)
  var year: String = null      

  feature("feature") {
    scenario("scenario") {
      println(ip2GeoTestJson)
      assert(year != null)
      assert(ip2GeoTestJson != null)
    }
  }

  def withFixture(test: NoArgTest): org.scalatest.Outcome = {
    year = test.configMap("year").asInstanceOf[String]
    try {
      test()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) It seems you changed code for a sample. 2) You have initialization or parsing problem. Nothing with scalatest. 3) From sample it seems useless to define vars. Especially out of method scope. 4) Again from sample you don't use `OneArgTest`

Comment: @Zernike My mistake, it was meant to be `NoArgTest` I made the correction. Yes I am having trouble during the initialization. In the second example, I moved all the JSON file parsing logic outside of the method and it works but I have to hardcode the file. I want to grab the filename from `configMap` and initialize it but I am not sure how to get it to work

Comment: Up to your example there is no need to "split" variable initialization. Set `val`  either in trait body (if it should be initialized only once) or in method body (other way).

Comment: @Zernike sorry, I am really new to scala. Would it be possible to show me some example code of your reply? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Set params before every test (see http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#withFixtureOneArgTest):

```
case class FixtureParams(year: String, ip2GeoTestJson: JValue)

class IP2GeoTestSuite extends FeatureSpec with SparkContextFixture {      

  feature("feature") {
    scenario("scenario") {
      println(ip2GeoTestJson)
      assert(year != null)
      assert(ip2GeoTestJson != null)
    }
  }

  override def withFixture(test: OneArgTest): org.scalatest.Outcome = {
    val year = test.configMap("year").asInstanceOf[String]
    val ip2GeoConfigFile = test.configMap("config").asInstanceOf[String]
    val ip2GeoUrl = getClass.getResourceAsStream(s"/$ip2GeoConfigFile")
    val ip2GeoJsonString = Source.fromInputStream(ip2GeoUrl).getLines.mkString("")
    val fixtureParam = FixtureParam(year, parseJson(ip2GeoJsonString))
    try {
    withFixture(test.toNoArgTest(fixtureParam))
    } finally {
    // Close resourses to avoid memory leak and unpredictable behaviour
      ip2GeoUrl.close()
    }
  }
}
```

Set params only once before any test will run (http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#beforeAndAfter):

```
class IP2GeoTestSuite extends FeatureSpec with BeforeAndAfter {

  var ip2GeoTestJson: JValue = null
  var year: String = null

  before {
    // Load config manually because configMap isn't available here. 
    val config = ConfigFactory.load()
    year = config.getString("year")
    val ip2GeoConfigFile = "ip2geofile.json"
    val ip2GeoUrl = getClass.getResourceAsStream(s"/$ip2GeoConfigFile")
    val ip2GeoJsonString = Source.fromInputStream(ip2GeoUrl).getLines.mkString("")
    ip2GeoUrl.close()
    System.out.println(ip2GeoJsonString)
    ip2GeoTestJson = parseJson(ip2GeoJsonString)
  }

  feature("feature") {
    scenario("scenario") {
      println(ip2GeoTestJson)
      assert(year != null)
      assert(ip2GeoTestJson != null)
    }
  }
}
```